# Align items in stackview closer to each other in horizontal axis

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have a stackView in horizontal axis

```
        let shareAndLikeStackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [likeCountLabel, shareCountLabel])
    shareAndLikeStackView.axis = .horizontal
    shareAndLikeStackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
```

[image]

[image]

This is what I get with .equalSpacing

[image]

I wonder is there an option in stackview which allows me to align shareCountLabel closer to LikesCountLabel with maybe just 8 padding between them? I have tried different distribution options but .fillProportionally is the closest one.

Answer (score 0):

Change your distribution value, you have asked it to fill proportionally, so that is what it is doing.  Try one of the other values to see if that is closer to what you want. You might also want to add some spacing.

```
shareAndLikeStackView.axis = .horizontal
shareAndLikeStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
shareAndLikeStackView.spacing = 8
```

There are a few different options such as .fill, .fillPropertionaly, .fillEqually, .equalSpacing

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I have tried all of them and still couldn't make them closer to each other with stackview.

Comment: Its hard to see the exact issue, can you color the labels so I can see where the borders are?

Comment: Updated with colored background

Comment: You could put you StackView inside another View, then bring the stack view constraints on left and right in by 40 pixels.  Then set 'spacing = 20` and keep the .equalSpacing.  They would then be closer to each other.